# sudo apt-get remove konqueror (equals uninstall Linux?)

Tags: debian, apt, kde, plasma5

In Debian 11 stable with KDE, why would uninstalling konqueror also remove libreoffice, xorg,etc? Why would it cause the installation of firefox-esr?

```
sudo apt-get remove konqueror
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apper apper-data coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1v5 coinor-libcoinutils3v5
  coinor-libosi1v5 cups-pk-helper fonts-symbola gir1.2-wnck-3.0 kdeaccessibility kmag kmousetool kmouth kontrast
  libkf5konq6 libqaccessibilityclient-qt5-0 libreoffice-calc libreoffice-draw libreoffice-help-common
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-kf5 libreoffice-plasma libreoffice-qt5 libwnck-3-0
  libwnck-3-common lp-solve mythes-en-us node-normalize.css orca print-manager python3-brlapi python3-cupshelpers
  python3-louis python3-smbc python3-speechd qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5 system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-udev task-desktop x11-apps x11-session-utils xbrlapi xinit xkbset xorg
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr
Suggested packages:
  fonts-stix | otf-stix
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kde-baseapps kde-plasma-desktop kde-standard konq-plugins konqueror task-kde-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 55.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 180 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

When I `sudo apt autoremove`, it doesn't try to remove those "no longer needed" packages. But when I try to remove konqueror, it says it will remove a whole lot of stuff that seems completely unrelated.

Comment: Why do you think that `konq-plugins` is "completely unrelated" to `konqueror`?  Do you have `apt-rdepends` installed?  What does `apt-rdepends -r konqueror` show?

Answer (score 2):

`konqueror` is a strong dependency of `kde-baseapps`, itself a strong dependency of `kde-plasma-desktop`, itself a strong dependency of `kde-standard`, itself a strong dependency of `task-kde-desktop`; it is a also a strong dependency of `konq-plugins`. So removing `konqueror` causes all those packages to be removed through cascading dependency removal.

The removal of those packages results in packages becoming autoremovable because the only reason *they* are present (as far as `apt` is concerned) is because they are pulled in by one of the removed packages. For example, `task-kde-desktop` recommends `apper`, so removing the former means the latter becomes autoremovable (assuming nothing else depends on it, strongly or weakly, which is the case here).

`firefox-esr` is installed as a result of removing `konqueror` because some other package you have installed has a strong dependency on the `www-browser` virtual package; `konqueror` provides that, removing it means it is no longer satisfied, but instead of removing the depending packages, `apt` chooses to install another `www-browser` provider (or more likely, an alternative direct dependency), `firefox-esr`.

Answer (score 1):

`kde-baseapps` depends upon the `konqueror` package, so removing konqueror causes kde-baseapps to be removed...which, in turn, causes the others to be removed.

`firefox-esr` is probably being installed because some other package depends on virtual package `www-browser` and firefox-esr is one of several packages that provide it.